# Why can I execute mutation function with null parameter with type being `String!`?

Tags: graphql

Simple table with one two rows. ID (incrementing int) and test_value (TEXT, nullable).

### 1. Query

```
query getData($test_value:String!) {
  testtable(where: {test_value: {_eq: $test_value}}) {
    test_value
  }
}
```

Variables

```
{"test_value":null}
```

Result

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "extensions": {
        "path": "$.selectionSet.testtable.args.where.test_value._eq",
        "code": "validation-failed"
      },
      "message": "unexpected null value for type \"String\""
    }
  ]
}
```

This is a **correct** that I expect.

### 2. Mutation

```
mutation InsertData($test_value: String!) {
  insert_testtable(objects: {test_value: $test_value}) {
    affected_rows
  }
}
```

Variables

```
{"test_value":null}
```

Result

```
{
    data: {
        insert_testtable: {
            affected_rows: 1
        }
    }
}
```

I expect and error (because of `test_value:String!` declaration), but I don't get it.
Why?

P.S.
testable schema looks like this:
`id: Int!`
`test_value: String`

Comment: Would you add the schema entries for the query and mutation to the post?  While you're at it, you might check if you pasted the wrong mutation result in your question.

Comment: use/pass "outer" object as variable (`$where`) ... `$test_value: String!` means variable (client/query defined) is not nullable but API/BE defined input type can be different, read docs/specs

Comment: @fedonev thanks! Fixed the result and added some info about the schema (I'm not sure if that is what where you asking for, though)

Comment: @xadm In mutation client/query defined is not nullable too, but  there is no error - that's what concerns me. I have checked docs/specs and various articles at the best of my abilities, but sadly I still don't get the difference.

Comment: `insert_testtable(objects: {test_value...` - check **input type** for `object` arg (and `test_value` prop) of this mutation - if it is a `String` then it can be `null`, it's more important (used in validation) than variable declaration

Comment: The missing clue is the mutation's _definition_.  Find the `insert_testable` line in your schema under `type Mutation {`. As @xadm says, the suspicion is that `insert_testable`'s _definition_ allows nullable inputs. You have shared how the client _calls_ the mutation, but not how it it _defined_ in the schema. It's a good question, keep at it!

Comment: @fedonev @xadm,  Indeed the mutation definition (insert_testtable) for `test_value` allows nulls (it is `String`). But why the mutation definition takes precedence over function argument definition? 
If I check query definition (testtable) for `test_value` i allows nulls (it is `String`).
But so both definitions are the same. And yet, when I do 'query' I get an error and when I do 'mutation' - it let the null value path through.

Is it somehow be possible that *variable declaration* is less important then *input_type* (stuff from schema) for queries, but is more important for mutations?

Comment: query/mutation doesn't matter ... you're mixing in next/3rd element - operator validator, probably for some reason `String` can't be compared to `null` using `_eq` - `null` is not a valid string value, `null` for args [validation] is used as their absence indicator, not a value

Answer (score 1):

My understanding of your issue:  Your schema has a mutation `insert_testtable` that takes a nullable `String` argument.  When you submit a named mutation operation with a non-nullable `String!` variable, the GraphQL server does not respond with an error.

The [GraphQL spec](https://spec.graphql.org/October2021/#sec-All-Variable-Usages-are-Allowed) says that is the expected behaviour for mutations and queries.  The spec says that if the type in the schema is nullable and of the same type as the variable, the operation is to be considered valid.  This is what's happening for your mutation.

If you are not seeing the same behaviour for the query, it is possible that your GraphQL server implementation differs from the spec.  You could check your server docs or their GitHub Issues.

For what it's worth, I checked that AppSync, AWS's GraphQL implementation, produces the expected behaviour for both queries and mutations.

Comment: Oh! So that's probably Hasura playing tricks on me. Thanks for clarification!